# Simple QThread example won't link properly

Tags: qt, visual-c++, clr, linker-errors, qthread

I want to use QThreadSynchronizer in my class, like so

```
#ifndef _MULTIWATCHER
#define _MULTIWATCHER

#include <QThread>
#include <QFutureSynchronizer>

#include "globals.h"

class MultiWatcher : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

signals:
    void allDone();

public:
    void run() override;
    QFutureSynchronizer<FocusResult> _sync;
};

#endif
```

However, when I try to build this I get the following linking errors

```
1>C:\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore/qvector.h(134): error C2182: 'at': 
illegal use of type 'void'
1>C:\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore/qvector.h(135): error C2182: '[]': 
illegal use of type 'void'
1>C:\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore/qvector.h(136): error C2182: '[]': 
illegal use of type 'void'

etc ...
```

Actually I get the same errors if I comment out the entire class (its also the same if QThreadSynchronizer  is replaced by QFuture) and just try to include the two include files, as if QThread and QFuture/QThreadSynchronizer are incompatible with each other. So the following also doesn't link!

```
#ifndef _MULTIWATCHER
#define _MULTIWATCHER

#include <QThread>
#include <QFuture>

#endif
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is `globals.h`?

Comment: The errors are (sort of) what I would expect if I inadvertently tried to use something like `QVector<void> ...`.  Please edit your question to show the actual code that causes the errors (not just the header).

Comment: As always: Try to produce a minimal compilable example. Most times this process already solves your problem... :-)

Comment: Because: If you `get the same errors if I comment out the entire class` then that means that the error is somewhere else.

Comment: As a side note, sometimes you can get this weird messages if you enable the CLR  support for your project, under C/C++->General or something like that (I can't tell by heart for vs2015). But if so, you could have trouble just compiling an helloword program...

Comment: When I comment out the #include <QFutureSynchronizer> line the errors disappear, so ifs definately something to do with this file (globals.h is my header file for the FocusResult structure).

Comment: Note: The fact that a change to a certain file eliminates the problem does *not* necessarily mean that that file is the source of the problem.

Comment: 1. Use source control. 2. Create a minimization branch, switch to it. 3. Start removing code aggressively, and rebuilding -- **each time removing the build folder**. After each removal that keeps the problem, **commit**. 4. Stop when you have about 30-50 lines. 5. You either know what the problem is by now, or you have something sensible to post in your question. As for ideas: You're doing something wrong, but refusing to tell us. How can that help us helping you? This isn't some obscure Qt bug, if I do exactly what you do, it works fine. Without more info, this question is off-topic.

Comment: I made a minimum project (after fixing rc.exe problems) and the problem was not observed. BTW If I knew what I was doing wrong you can be sure that I would tell you. I think I will do more detailed build output and see what is including the file that gives the errors, maybe that will point out the mistake, otherwise like you say I will have to try to remove stuff until the problem disappears.

Comment: What's strange is that this error only occurs if the QFuture header file is included in my header, if it is included in the cpp file, it builds fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by changing the "Common Language RunTime Support" option from "Common Language RunTime Support /clr" to "No Common Language RunTime Support" for the moc_multiwatcher.cpp file that QT generates. These files are in "Generated Files"->Debug section of the Solution Browser, the clr setting for this file can be accessed by right clicking on it and going to properties. I hope this is useful for other people having strange linking errors in their c++/clr/QT visual studio projects.